# Transform a normal distribution to linear

Tags: javascript, math, statistics, distribution

I have an array of about 1000 floats, all between 0 and 1. I want to show them in a bar chart where the highest 10 values clearly stand out.

The problem is my data appears to be normally distributed, i.e., there are a lot of 0.999943 and 0.99902 values. So if I plot all the values, you won't clearly see the top 10.

What kind of function can I pass the array values through in order to exaggerate the variance at the higher end of the range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `0 < Your data < 1`, what about using [Math.log10](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log10) to calculate the base 10 logarithm of your data?

For example, `Math.log10(0.999943) = -0.000024755491006670377` while `Math.log10(0.99902 ) = -0.00042581727682710913`, then if you like, you can multiple the result with `100000` and get the result `-2.4` and `-42`, the variance is exaggerated and their relationship is not changed, because `log10` is an monotone increasing function.

Answer (score 0):

For any continuous random variate X with cumulative distribution function F(x), transforming the observations by F(x) makes them uniformly distributed between zero and one.  Expressing the same idea in a slightly conceptually different way, present the p-values rather than the raw observations to highlight the extreme values.

This has the benefit that if the transformed value is above 0.95 for instance, you can directly state that that observation is in the top 5% of the distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @pjs but I'm afraid that's above me!

Comment: @Seano This is basically just getting the index of the values.